# Is the an IDE/plugin/smth which can highlight (heat map) code according to how old it is?

Tags: git, interface, ide, heatmap, codehighlighter

I'm looking for PHP IDE, but I can't find ANY IDE which does something like that. All the code is traceable back in time in git or any other version control, right? So, it would be cool to have a "dust view" mode, to see which code is there for ages (cold, grey), which was changed recently (hot, bright).
Like a heat maps for web pages - but for code? I think it might be usable for

P.S. Might be not an IDE feature, but a github functionality for example?

Comment: Eclipse can do "Team -> Show Annotations" which show this in the leftmost column.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen is there a way to see how it looks like? Can you point me to a screenshot or shomething like that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen found. Ok, better then nothing, but it shown WHO modified the code, not WHEN it was modified. Well, it's written there, but the idea is to see with one sight where is the fresh code here.

Comment: write a small PHP-script that massages the output of "git blame -p _file_" into what you want.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sorry ) Thanks for your input and attention ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned, the 'blame' or 'annotate' command of most version control programs has the information that you need (the date and revision that each line was changed). SmartSVN allows you to [color by age](http://www.smartsvn.com/documentation/annotate) (sorry, it doesn't have a screenshot), and [git-age](https://github.com/krig/git-age/wiki) also does that for git repos.

Comment: @AlekseyKolupaev If I answered your question, please mark it using the checkmark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not IDE per se, just TortoiseHG (Mercurial), in which "Annotate files" in THG-menu have this feature

[image]

(fresh lines showing hotter and redder, most left column show exact freshness in revision number)